# Image Not Loading Crafty.js

Tags: javascript, crafty

I am experimenting with Crafty.js, and I have called .image() on an entity, and the image is not loading. When I look through the web inspector, I can see that the cloud entity exists, and that the cloud image is found, but it is not showing up. What is the proper way to load an image on an entity, and what is wrong with my code?

mainCrafty.js:

```
Crafty.e('myCloud, 2D, DOM, Image')        // cloud
        .attr({x: 300, y: 10, w: 45, h: 30})
        .image('images/cloud.png');
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
index.html
images/
   cloud.png
scripts/
   crafty.js
   mainCrafty.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the image was to large for the size I wanted it to be, so I was only seeing the corner of it (which was blank).